# How to fix blurred items in a combobox

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

When i scale down my application to a phone screen, all the items in ALL of the comboboxes get blurry

```
private ComboBox<City> cityCB = new ComboBox<>("City");


<dom-module id="combobox-style" theme-for="vaadin-text-field">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host(#input) [part="value"]{
                border-right: solid 2px black;
            }
            :host(#input) [part="input-field"]{
                background-color: white;
                border: solid 1px lightgray;
                border-radius: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

this is my combobox and ALL of its styling.

http://prntscr.com/nfrbhw - this is the image of how it looks on a phone screen, also im using vaadin flow 13.0.4. Any idea if this is a vaadin problem or a me problem?

Comment: The image doesn't look blurred to me. I can easily make out the number IDs and the names of the Polish cities, for example `1000 Ljubljana`

Comment: Vaadin itself is not responsible of the scaling, it is done by the browser. Thus it would interesting to know which browser and phone model it is.

Comment: @Abra ye its readable, but its a bit blurry, you can definetly tell the difference between this and full screen :  https://prnt.sc/ng34rl , nice try but its not polish :D slovenian

Comment: @TatuLund its done in chrome and i just scale it down to samsung s5 resolution via console : https://prnt.sc/ng3544 , and i checked and it looks perfectly fine in mozzila firefox

Comment: Oops. Please excuse me. I got it mixed up with Lublin.

Comment: This seems to be some sort of issue with Chrome dev tools. First I was not able to reproduce the issue, but then I noticed that if I set the zoom factor to be e.g. 75% or 125% instead of 100% there is in certain fonts some blur effect. I assume this is not happening with real device.

Comment: ye,i came to the same conclussion, cuz if i just scale the window down normally instead of with dev tools it looks fine